# A consequence of Wilson's Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, congruences

By Wilson's Theorem we know that $$(p-1)! \equiv -1 \mod p.$$

A consequence of this is apparently  $$(p-(k+1))!k! \equiv (-1)^{k+1} \mod p$$ where $0 \leq k \leq p-1$.

I was told to think of it like so,

Let $0 \leq i \leq p-1$.  Then $(p-i)\equiv -i \mod p.$

I'm interested in proceeding in the above way, but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: Write $(p-1)! = [(p-1)(p-2)...(p-k)](p-(k+1))!$ then reduce each of the first $k$ brackets mod $p$.

Comment: The first part reduces to $-1$, $-2$, etc correct?

Comment: Yes, so overall what will you get?

Comment: -k!(p-(k+1))! I believe

Comment: Not exactly...it could be either of $\pm k!(p-(k+1))!$. You only know how many minus signs there are.

Comment: So you get $(p-1)! = (-1)^{k} k!(p-(k+1))! \bmod p$.

Comment: This is really interesting.

Comment: Do you see how to proceed now?

Comment: Also can you see how from this you can now prove that the binomial coefficients $\binom{p-1}{k}$ are all $\pm 1 \bmod p$? (In fact further that $\binom{p-1}{k} \equiv (-1)^k \bmod p$)

Comment: Let me make sure I understand everything.  First we have $(p-1)!=(p-1)(p-2)\cdots(p-k)(p-(k+1))!=\pm k!(p-(k+1))!.$  I'm not sure how this is equivalent to $(-1)^{k+1}$ modulo $p$.

Comment: My point about the $\pm$ was that you don't know the sign of it. You must be more precise. $(p-1)(p-2)...(p-k) \equiv (-1)(-2)...(-k) = (-1)^k k! \bmod p$.

Comment: I think you are nearly there so I have provided a full solution.

Comment: What I'd love to see is a counting proof...

Comment: See also: [Proving a congruence using Wilson Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2819011)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ An equivalent way to state Wilson's theorem is that any complete system of representatives of nonzero remainders mod $\,n\,$ has product $\equiv -1.\,$ In particular this is true for any sequence of $\,p\,$ consecutive integers, after removing its $\rm\color{#c00}{multiple}$ of $\,p.\,$  Your special case is the sequence $\, -k,\,-k\!+\!1,\ldots,-1,\require{cancel}\cancel{\color{#c00}0,} 1,2,\ldots, (p\!-\!k\!-\!1),\,$ with product $(-1)^k k!\, (p\!-\!k\!-\!1)!\equiv -1.\ $ **QED**

**Remark** $\ $ The essence of Wilson's theorem is group-theoretical, so if you know a little group theory I highly recommend that you look at some [prior posts](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+%28dubuque+OR+%22math+gems%22+OR+%22key+ideas%22%29+Wilson+group) on the group-theoretic viewpoint, which more clearly highlight the innate [involution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29) symmetry (negation/inversion "reflections")

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach: $$\binom{p-1}{k} \equiv (-1)^k\pmod p\,; 0\leq k\leq p-1$$ by induction, since $\binom{p-1}{k}+\binom{p-1}{k+1} = \binom{p}{k+1} \equiv 0\pmod p$ when $k<p-1$. (When $k=0$ this is obvious.)

But $\binom{p-1}{k} = \frac{(p-1)!}{k!(p-1-k)!}$ So: $$(-1)^k k!(p-1-k)! \equiv (p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod p$$

And finally:

$$k!(p-1-k)! \equiv (-1)^{k+1}\pmod p$$

Comment: Very interesting indeed. I can see an alternative proof of $p\mid2^{p-1}-1$ showing up...

Comment: Alternatively the end congruence gives a proof of the binomial coeff congruence at the top.

Comment: Sure, but it's really much easier to prove directly what $\binom{p-1}{k}=(-1)^{k}$, which doesn't even require Wilson. @fretty

Comment: I think (mod $k$) should be (mod $p$) in the first line.

Comment: Yep, thanks @Tad.

Comment: Also: ${p-1\choose k}\equiv{-1\choose k}=(-1)\cdots(-k)/k! = (-1)^k\,({\rm mod\ }p)$

Answer (score 1):

**A numerical example:**

Let $p=47$. All congruences will be modulo $47$, so out of laziness we leave out the modulus. We know that $46!\equiv -1$.

Now we think  about $45!$. Note that $(45!)(46)\equiv -1$. 
But $46\equiv -1$. Thus
$$45!(-1)\equiv -1.$$
Next we  think about $44!$. Note that $(44!)(45)(46)\equiv -1$. But $45\equiv -2$ and $46\equiv -1$, so
$$(44!)(-2)(-1)\equiv -1,$$
or equivalently
$$(44!)(-1)^2(2!)\equiv -1.$$
Next we look at $43!$. Note that $(43!)(44)(45)(46)\equiv -1$.
But $44\equiv -3$, $45\equiv -2$, and $46\equiv -1$. We conclude that
$$(43!)(-1)^3(3!)\equiv -1.$$
Next we look at $42!$. Since $(42!)(43)(44)(45)(46)\equiv -1$, an analysis like the ones above shows that
$$(42!)(-1)^4(4!)\equiv -1.$$
Also, we have
$$(41!)(-1)^5(5!)\equiv -1,$$
and so on.
To get the slightly different form of the OP, in the $42!$ case multiply both sides by $(-1)^4$. In the $41!$ case, multiply both sides by $(-1)^5$. That gets rid of the minus signs on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Writing $(p-1)! = (p-1)(p-2)...(p-k)(p-(k+1))!$ and reducing mod $p$ gives:

$(p-1)! \equiv (-1)^k (p-(k+1))!k! \bmod p$.

Now using Wilson's theorem gives:

$(-1)^k (p-(k+1))! k! \equiv -1 \bmod p$.

Multiplying both sides of the congruence by $(-1)^k$ gives:

$(p-(k+1))! k! \equiv (-1)^{k+1} \bmod p$.

Comment: +1 I don't understand why this got no votes. It's a natural way to proceed. See also my answer which shows how to view it as arising from Wilson's Theorem applied to a different system of remainder reps.